# How can I apply the decorator pattern with CoffeeScript to extend an object?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, decorator

I'm trying to create a node module that will interact with the `github` API, but will cache results in redis. You can follow my progress at https://github.com/shamoons/github-redis-etag (please, fork me!). As a base, I'm using the [`github` package](https://www.npmjs.org/package/github) by mikedeboer.

What I want to do is create a class that extends the functionality of the `GitHubApi` module and calls some redis magic before calling the Github calls. What I have so far is:

```
_ = require 'lodash'
base91 = require 'base91'
GitHubApi = require 'github'
redis = require 'redis'
util = require 'util'

class GitHubETag extends GitHubApi
  repos = {}

  constructor: (defaults = {}) ->
    @github = new GitHubApi
      version: '3.0.0' || defaults.version?
      debug: false || defaults.false?
      protocol: 'http' || defaults.protocol?
      host: null || defaults.host?
      pathPrefix: '' || defaults.pathPrefix?
      timeout: null || defaults.timeout?

    @redisClient = redis.createClient ('6379' || defaults.redis?.port?), ('127.0.0.1' || defaults.redis?.host?)

    githubObjects = ['events', 'gists', 'gitdata', 'issues', 'markdown', 'orgs', 'pullRequests', 'repos', 'search', 'statuses', 'user']

    _.each githubObjects, (object) =>
      @object = {}

      _.each _.keys(@github[object]), (key) =>
        fn = @github[object][key]
        @object[key] = @github[object][key]
        console.log "#{object}:#{key}"
```

which I realize is all sorts of wrong. To instantiate it, I'm doing:

```
github = new GitHubETag
  version: '3.0.0'
  redis:
    port: '6379'
    host: '127.0.0.1'

console.log github
```

which is also wrong, because this returns the same object as the `GitHubApi` except with `github:` equaling all of that. So if anyone has any advice or tips, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your problem is this: `@github = new GitHubApi(args...)`

you don't have to call new from inside the constructor with the parent class, it defeats the purpose. and since your constructor is the only method in your class body then that all just gets returned when you call new on the subclass. You can also rewrite your constructor for default arguments as below.

```coffee
class GitHubETag extends GitHubApi
  repos = {}

  constructor: ({@version, @debug}) ->
    @version ?= '3.0.0'
    @debug ?= false
    etc..


instance = new GitHubETag(version: '2.0.0')
instance.version #=> '2.0.0'
instance.debug #=> false
```

I'm not really sure of the use of the each loops at the bottom of the constructor so I can't really comment there, but if you are just trying to set methods dynamically on the instance, you dont have to, because you are *extending* the superclass. if you dont need any subclass variance to those methods, they are already defined. eg, with the code above you should then be able to do:

```coffee
instance.events #=> function
superclass = new GitHubApi()
instance.events == superclass.events #=> true
```

to override, or do work before the parent class method, define the method, do the work and then call super:

```coffee
class GitHubETag extends GitHubApi
  gists: ()->
    console.log "doing work"
    super

instance.gists() #=> logs and calls through
```

Comment: The purpose of the loop is to eventually do some logic BEFORE calling the superclass's functions

Comment: then just declare the function on the subclass and do the work before calling super. Updating the answer to give an example.

Comment: But I don't want to have to do this for EVERY call. The thing I'm doing BEFORE calling the superclass is the SAME in all cases

Comment: you should only ever have to declare the 'work' once. If it is work you want to do in the constructor (what would happen when you call `new` then write that code in the constructor and then call super. if they are specific bodies of work that occur before the instance method is called, then follow the `gists` example above. My read of your example however tells me you may have some misconceptions of how prototype inheritance works.